# JHipster entity database table

Tags: jhipster

I have created different entities in JHipster. I want to know if a new database table is created automatically for each entity or I should create them myself?
I read JHipster's [Creating an entity](https://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-entity/) but it did not mention about this!

Answer (score 1):

Everything in the list at the top of the page you linked to ([Creating an Entity](https://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-entity/)) is created for you.  This includes a database table and a liquibase change set, which tracks changes to your database.  By default, the table name matches the entity name.

The table is created on your first run of the application after generating the entity.  For updates to your tables, see the Liquibase section of the [Using in Development](https://jhipster.github.io/development/) docs.

Comment: I just ran everything again, but a few of the entities have their tables created, not all of them, and as the result I get `error.internalServerError` on the front end. seems strange to me!
I also tried to update the single entities by `yo jhipster:entity` but I get another error as `Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-rev'` that I am trying to resolve now!!!

Comment: There are several things that could go wrong.  If you changed an entity after generating it, the table will also require a change.  See the Using in Development link from my main post in that case.  Your gulp issue sounds like something went wrong installing your node_moduels.  Try deleting that folder and rerunning `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Yes Database table will create automatically,,  also you can create database table your self thats your choice

Comment: This is not an answer, please add this text as it should be, as a comment.